# clang9(or trunk) vs gcc9: member array size as non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

I have the following mock code

```cpp
#include <array>
template<int N>
struct S {
    std::array<int, N> m{};
};

template<int N>
auto copy (S<N> const& i) {
    return S<i.m.size()>{};
}

int main() {
    copy(S<1>{});
}
```

Is `i.m.size()` supposed to be a valid non-type template parameter?
clang9 sais no, gcc9 sais yes: https://godbolt.org/z/PoHjH8

I kind of "get" clang because `i` is not constexpr, but since the `i.m.size()` is still known at compile time, gcc's approach makes more sense to me.
Who is correct here?

Comment: By the standard the answer is no, clang is right here. There is a duplicate question, I'll try to find it.

Comment: GCC probably does not complain because the call to `size()` is optimized away and replaced by a constant.